# Update state on leading whitespace in React component

Tags: reactjs

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: "content",
      errorMessage: "this is a required field",
      required: true
    };
  }
  render() {
    const updateValue = val => {
      this.setState({ value: val.target.value });
    };

    const handleClick = () => {
      if (this.state.value.trim() === "") {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: "Cant have leading whitespace" });
      }
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          onChange={updateValue}
          value={this.state.value}
          type="text"
          required={this.state.required}
        />
        {this.state.value.length < 1 ? (
          <div>{this.state.errorMessage}</div>
        ) : null}
        <button onClick={handleClick}>OK</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have the above component that renders the `errorMessage` state if the input is empty. I am also trying to update this `errorMessage` state to read `"Cant have leading whitespace"` if the user fills the input box with white space and hits `OK` button.

What I expect to happen is once the button is clicked is the following:

```
  if (this.state.value.trim() === "") {
    this.setState({ errorMessage: "Cant have leading whitespace" });
  }
```

That is, it checks if the `value` state only consists of empty string and updates the `errorMessage` state accordingly.

However, this the state is not being updated the way I expect it to. How can I fix this issue? Thanks!

I have a working demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/2x846p0p5y

Comment: What exactly do you expect? The state updates (I verified), but the error message won't show because `this.state.value.length < 1` won't be fulfilled (a string with even only a single whitespace has length >= 1).

Comment: what about trailing spaces? don't matter to you?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the code like below trim the state value here also

```
{this.state.value.trim().length < 1 ? (
      <div>{this.state.errorMessage}</div>
 ) : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Regular expression `match(/s+|\s+$/g, "")`

```
 const handleClick = () => {
      var hasSpaces = this.state.value.match(/s+|\s+$/g, "");
        this.setState({ errorMessage: hasSpaces && "Cant have leading whitespace" });
    };
```

And remove all those conditions from the render Just use plain text as if it is null it will not render it

```
<div>{this.state.errorMessage}</div>
```

However, If you are concerned about trailing spaces too then use this expression -

```
.match(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your if condition by this:

```
  const handleClick = () => {
  if (this.state.value.trim().length === 0) {
    this.setState({ errorMessage: "Cant have leading whitespace" });
  }
};
```

Hope this works for you